# FCM not working push notification sound android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a push notification to my phone using Firebase console , but when the application is minimized, the sound and the title of the notification does not work does not work, and when the application is in the foreground working properly , what is the reason that the behavior notifications be different ?

[image]

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```java
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
    <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
```

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Which payload are you using, notification or data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the notification message type which only shows a notification when the app is in the foreground. You need to use data message type to get notifications (and sounds, vibrations, etc) when the app is in the background. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529317/firebase-notification-is-not-working-when-activity-is-in-background-or-not/40695594#40695594).