# Firebase notification is not working when activity is in background or not

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have same coding as provided by firebase sample code. It works fine when activity is in foreground state or opened. But when activity is closed or in background state then it does not work properly. Problem is like that...

1. App icon is not shown of application.
2. By default take app name as a title of notification

And when app is in background state or not opened on device that time notification occurs then LogCat shows following details :

```
09-16 15:55:56.056 12113-12113/com.testdemofb D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-16 15:55:56.089 12113-12113/com.testdemofb D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-16 15:55:56.176 12113-12113/com.testdemofb I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
09-16 15:55:56.177 12113-12113/com.testdemofb I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
09-16 15:55:56.286 12113-12113/com.testdemofb I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-16 15:55:56.518 12113-12147/com.testdemofb I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
```

if any solution for that then help me

Thanks...

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
package com.testdemofb;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification BodyLocalize: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBodyLocalizationKey());
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification TitleLocalize: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitleLocalizationKey());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }


}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(bm)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file put like this between *application* tag...

```
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:process="remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: can you share your implementation of generating notofication

Comment: sharing my code for generating notification @RaguSwaminathan

Comment: do you check whether the sendnotification method is called or not. ? try logging there and check

Comment: It's called when app in foreground state but not called in app closed and background state @RaguSwaminathan

Comment: call sendnotification method outside of if statements and check if that works ?

Comment: not worked outside of if statement also...@RaguSwaminathan

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of messages that FCM uses, viz. notification and data. Read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options). I think you are sending a notification. You need to send a data message.

Something like this.

```
{
"to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
 "Nick" : "Mario",
 "body" : "great match!",
 "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
},
}
```

Comment: can you please add more details

Answer (score 0):

Send notification from Firebase console : Works for both background and foreground app

Instead of onMessageReceived, override zzm() of FirebaseMessagingService and create your custom notification from here

```
@Override
public void zzm(Intent intent) {
    Log.e(TAG, "zzm : " + intent);
    createNotification();        
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think FireBase works like this...
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

[image]

Comment: im not sure why people thumbs down this but this seems like how it works.