# How to process push notification when app is destroyed?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Now I am processing push notification using FCM. It works well when app is in foreground.

I'd like to process the notification even when the app is on background or is destroyed.

I googled about it for a few days, but couldn't find the solution yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Firebase or something different?

Comment: I am using Firebase now

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529317/firebase-notification-is-not-working-when-activity-is-in-background-or-not/40695594#40695594

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829

Answer (score 0):

So, if you use firebase, you should send data notification (json contained data section, not notification) according to this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Then override FirebaseMessagingService with onMessageReceived, and there you will receive push message. You have to also register this service in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <service android:name=".service.FirebaseMessageService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Yes, I did it already in AndroidMagnifiest.xml.
Now I am getting the push when app is running.

Comment: And do you get notification in status bar when app is in background? Could you post an example json which app is receiving?

Comment: just using console.firebase.com

Comment: When you are using firebase console, your app is getting push of type "notification" - so when app is in background, service is not getting push. You have to send message manually e.g. via Postman

Comment: so there is no solution while I am using firebase console ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.